# Flagging a Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

We do a lot of Jenkins System Groovy Scripts to check our Jenkins configuration for things, such as someone allowing Anonymous access when they shouldn't.  But there are times when we want to flag a job to be ignored in these self-audits.

My thought was to set an Environment Variable via the EnvInject plugin.  But I can't see where you can use the Groovy System Scripts to get these values?

Anyone know how to do this?  Alternatives to this method would also be helpfull.

Comment: Why not just put it as in exclusion in the Groovy script itself? Like adding a grep to filter out the known "ok" jobs?

Comment: Each individual job creator needs to be able to do this as a 'self service' so we don't want to maintain a list of jobs or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use obtain the environmental variables from a System Groovy Script using the following:

```
def myVar = build.getEnvironment(listener).get('JOB_NAME')
println "JOB_NAME = " + myVar
```

Comment: I don't think that will work for us.  It gets the information from the currently running job and we need it from the job definition.  As an example: 

Jenkins.instance.items.each {
    println it.getName
  }

Comment: So, you want to iterate over each job, and based upon something that is configured in that job (a flag of some sort based on env. var), you want to further scan the job configuration for common faults?  You can use the 'myVar' (which contains the job name) in the above example to obtain the job object and then go from there (check for env, var, etc.), but I will add a more complete example after I do some testing.

Comment: This gets the information I need but I do not like the solution.  Basically it reads the config.xml to get the variables injected.

    path = jobHome+ '/'+item.getFullDisplayName() + '/config.xml';
    path = path.replace(' » ', '/jobs/');

    theFile = new File(path)
  
    def root1 = new XmlSlurper().parseText(theFile.text)

            root1.buildWrappers.EnvInjectBuildWrapper.info.propertiesContent.each {

    println path + ' ' + theFile.isFile()
    println '    ENVINJECT ['+it+']'
    }